# Angular directives and server requests

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm just wondering is it a good practice to make http GET request to fetch data inside an angular directive? Directive's behavior is dependent on that data.

So the main complexity is to get it before it's compiled (to add special classes to elements for example).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest putting the code making the HTTP requests in a service.

Comment: Isn't $http already a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO directives should consume the model, not get, post or manipulate the model. I would make an attribute in your directive called 'src' or similar that would allow your directive to bind to a controller scope. Then do the get in your controller. Have that get update $scope and therefore your directive as well.

Comment: @Fresheyeball I like your idea but creating simple attr like ``src`` doesn't allow to get data, ``<div my-dir="string" src="{{ServerDataFromCtrl}}"></div>`` ServerDataFromCtrl is empty..

Comment: @Fresheyeball maybe I need one more directive like ``my-src`` :)

Comment: maybe you're not isolating the scope in directive

Comment: @kosmetika no, you can isolate scope and do this as well. Though you don't always need directives to have their own scope. If you wish to isolate you can do something like $scope.$parent[attrs.src]

Comment: thanks, btw i see another problem here - seems request is not yet finished before directive is ready.. so I get an empty array, but in web inspector ``$parent.DataThatIneed`` is not empty..

Comment: @Kosmetika that's not a problem, directive should $watch the scope. That way ANY future updates to the model are reflected in the directive.

Comment: yeah, but ``$watch`` doesn't work for me - maybe i'm doing something wrong? ``scope.$watch(scope.DataThatIneed, function (old, newly) { .. });`` ?

Comment: First make sure you are watching the right scope. Second DataThatIneed should be coming from an attribute on the directive as discussed, otherwise it violates encapsulation. Third the first argument in $watch should be a string.

Comment: the tricky thing is that i'm doing it that way ``scope.$parent.$watch('NeededData', functio...`` and if ``NeededData`` is static array like ``[{a:1}, {a:2}]`` it watches this for me but when it is request - watcher provides empty array ``[]``..

Comment: oh man, i found the solution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12965702/2117550 this is crazy :)

Comment: Cool, glad you got `$watch` working. Depending on your setup passing `true` as a third argument could be needed. Angular's value checking methodology is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, create a model that holds all needed data for your directive. Create a directive and use `ng-model` atribute in the markup to bind the model to the directive. Then in your directive's `link` method, watch any changes in this model using the $scope.$watch method. Here is a good example integrating a flot chart with angularjs: http://jsfiddle.net/TDwGF/3/

Comment: yeah, it's good example but it's working so far because you do not isolate the scope in directive, put before ``link`` - ``scope: {}`` and you'll see that everything breaks..

Comment: so another question appears here - is it good to isolate scope in this situation or not..

Comment: I like the idea of using ngModel as the binding attribute for a custom directive, but feel its got some connotations regarding a 2 way binding that is not necessarily appropriate for a custom directive. What do you think?

Comment: @Kosmetika yes, if you give it an empty scope then it won't work because the model won't be in the scope. Maybe you can create a new scope and yet add the model there? I never tried this.

Comment: hm, your solution is good, but nevertheless i received an empty array in directive ``$scope.dataThatIrequestFromServer``, maybe request is not yet ready, how can I overcome it? ``$watch`` doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

It's important to add that if you use `$watch` listening `$resource` you should add `true` at the end:

```
scope.$watch('NeededDataLoadedFromServer', function(newval, oldval) {}, true);
```

Comment: It would be helpful to describe "why" you need the "true" at the end. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$watch - last argument is "objectEquality", a boolean that will "Compare object for equality rather than for reference."