# Angular Resource - how to check if a resource instance has any unsaved changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-resource

I want to be able to tell whether an $resource instance has been modified by the user - that is, whether its current state is different than what has been initially loaded from the server && has not yet been $saved. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you get a resource, and then put it on the current $scope so that it can be edited by a user:

```
$scope.question = Questions.get({id:"19615328"});
```

You can then watch it for changes like this:

```
// some flag, name it anything
$scope.userChange = false;
$scope.$watch('question', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue && newValue != oldValue){
        $scope.userChange = true;
        // if you want to you can even do this, this will trigger on every change though
        $scope.question.$save();
    }
}, true);
```

( *Pretty much everything from down here is the result of the extra questions from the chat below* )

Then whenever you want to check if it has been changed `$scope.userChange` can tell you if a change occurred. And when you save the object, reset the `$scope.userChange`.

You can even do this

```
$scope.$watch('question', function() {
    $scope.question.$save();
}, true);
```

Obviously you'd want to add some sort of throttle or "debounce" system so it waits a second or so, once you have this in place any change to the object will cause a save via `$scope.$watch`.

And in case you want to check for null, for when you have not yet received the actual object.

```
$scope.$watch('question', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // dont save if question was removed, or just loaded
    if(newValue != null && oldValue != null){
        $scope.question.$save();
    }
}, true);
```

You could even wrap the `Questions.get` call, see [this questions for answers on how you can do this on the service & factory level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11181271/1066946), to do something like this.

```
Questions.getAndAutosave = function(options){
    var instance = Questions.get(options);
    $scope.$watch(function(){
            return instance;
        },
        function(newValue, oldValue){
            if (newValue === oldValue) return;
            if(newValue != null && oldValue != null){
                instance.$save();
            }
        }, true);
    return instance;
};
```

Then whenever you call `Questions.getAndAutosave`, whatever it returns is already being watched, and will be auto-`$save`'d. The reason we do `if (newValue === oldValue) return;` is because `$watch` fires as soon as you call it, and then watches for changes. We don't need to save on the first call.

Comment: Unfortunately the $watch will also be triggered when $get is executed, because $scope.question changes from null to object... I want something that would only report unsaved changes when user makes the changes, not when the data is being pulled from the server.

Comment: The idea is you watch it _after_ you receive the response. Or; give $watch a second callback, ( this receives the old and new value ), so you can check if the old value was null. ( Or if the new value is null ? :-) )

Comment: Also, do you think that such functionality could be implemented directly in the service? I know I can augment a $resource with additional functions. Implementing such features in every controller for every resource might be tedious and far from elegant

Comment: I've added a short sample on what you could do, there's another question with many options on how to configure it at the service / factory level.

Comment: For some reason the  `if(newValue != null && oldValue != null){` condition in $watch is not sufficient. I have implemented it and right  off the bat after the resource is loaded the $scope.userChange flag is set to true, even though the user has not yet made any changes to the object. Any ideas on how to correct that?

Comment: Add some `console.log`-ging whats the actual value of newValue and oldValue?

Comment: Here you can see the logged values in the js console: http://jsfiddle.net/Tt4b5/2/

Comment: You seem to be right, I read up on the documentation and `$watch` always fires the instant you call it, this is apparently the expected behaviour, so you'll have to add a check to see if the values are not the same ( As we don't want to get hit by the first call ) Updated question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40382/discussion-between-philipp-and-groovy354)

Comment: I think a combination of *object* $watch (`true` as third argument), properly checking `newVal` and `oldVal` and setting something like a `$changed` on the `question` instance (restrict it there, don't polute $scope) may do the job.

Comment: I found this some months later, got stuck on the $scope.$watch('question'... expression in the answer. It won't work unless third argument is `true` as mentioned in previous comment (if not, it'll only watch for the reference to the resource to change, not the resource data, and the watch expression will never fire after initial load). See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135864/scope-watch-is-not-updating-value-fetched-from-resource-on-custom-directive

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution that both does not treat downloading data from server as user change and is implemented directly in the service itself. It might not be the most efficient solution possible, but provides exactly the functionality I want,

```
app.factory('testService', ['$resource', '$rootScope', function($resource, $rootScope){
var test = $resource('/api/words/:id', {id: '@id'});

test.orig_get = test.get;

test.get = function(options){
    var instance = test.orig_get(options, function(){
        instance.unsaved = false;
        $rootScope.$watch(function(){
            return instance;
        }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
           if(angular.equals(newValue, oldValue)){
                return;
           }
           var changed_indexes = [];
           for(var i in newValue){
                if(!angular.equals(newValue[i], oldValue[i])){
                    changed_indexes.push(i);
                }
           }
           if(newValue != null && oldValue != null && !(changed_indexes.length==1 && changed_indexes[0]=='unsaved')){
                console.log('detected change. setting unsaved to true');
                instance.unsaved = true;
            }

        }, true);
    });
    return instance;
}

test.prototype.orig_save = test.prototype.$save;

test.prototype.$save = function(options){
    return this.orig_save(options, function(){
        this.unsaved = false;           
    })
}

return test;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the initial object, then compare when you need to check.

```
master = null
resource = Resource.get({id:1}, function() {
  master = angular.copy(resource)
})
function isModified() {
  return !angular.equals(resource, master)
}
```

Comment: Although this solves the problem, it is very expensive to an object comparison. If you use a function like this in the view, this expensive comparison algorithm will run on every digest cycle, making the app slow.