# $scope.$watch in angularjs to update value from service

Tags: angularjs, controller, watch

I have a service which periodically updates, I am trying to put its updated value in the front-end.

My service looks like -

```
akiRepair.factory("webService", ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope){
  ...
  this.repair = {};
  this.updates = {};
  this.parts = {};
  var t = this;
  ...
  var handle_subscribe = function(res){
      if(res.result == false){
        console.log("Unable to subscribe");
      }else{
        //update top widget

        t.repair.head = res.order.equipment.description;
        t.repair.subDate = res.order.submitted;
        t.repair.des = res.order.description.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');

        //update left widget
        t.updates = res.order.labour;

        //update right widget
        t.parts = res.order.charges;

      }
    };
```

while the controller looks like -

```
akiRepair.controller("restCtrl", ['$scope', 'webService', function($scope, webService){
  $scope.repair = {};
  $scope.repair.head = "Please wait";
  $scope.webService = webService;
  $scope.$watch('webService.repair', function(newVal){
    console.log("Hello I am updated");//it displayed on console
    console.log($scope.webService); //this comes undefined
    console.log(newVal);//this comes undefined
    $scope.repair = $scope.webService.repair;
  });
```

I am able to watch the repair variable of webService but I am not able to get its updated value. I referred to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mchrobok/JE78Q/4/)

Thanks

Comment: This is a shot in the dark but can you try function(newVal, oldVal) instead of function(newVal)

Comment: I believe $broadcast would be the correct choice for this purpose.

Comment: That would be certainly but I am bit concerned that why it is not working

Comment: Look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135864/angularjs-scope-watch-is-not-updating-value-fetched-from-resource-on-custom?rq=1)... I hope this helps....

Comment: Do you return anything from your .factory function?